# spotify/dockerfile-maven plugin: Could not build image: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection

Tags: java, dockerfile, maven-plugin, spotify, sslexception

maven-plugin to build my docker image.

Whenever I run `dockerfile:build`

I always get this error :

```
"failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.6:build (default-cli) on project XXX: Could not build image"
"Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"
```

I will include the error log in the end.

Would you please take a look on what is wrong here?

This is the pom.xml file I am using for this plugin.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build</goal>
                    <goal>push</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <repository>company/imagename</repository>
            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The docker version is : 17.06.2-ce

OS: Windows 10.

I checked "general--Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375" and also add insecure registries in the docker for windows.

I also add DOCKER_HOST="tcp://localhost:2375" and DOCKER_CERT_PATH in my system variables.

Error log after dockerfile-build:

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not build image
at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage(BuildMojo.java:185)
at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.execute(BuildMojo.java:105)
at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.tryExecute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:240)
at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:229)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.propagate(DefaultDockerClient.java:2512)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:2443)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.version(DefaultDockerClient.java:501)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.authRegistryHeader(DefaultDockerClient.java:2555)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build(DefaultDockerClient.java:1396)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.build(DefaultDockerClient.java:1365)
at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage(BuildMojo.java:178)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: **javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?**
at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:2441)
... 31 more
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:481)
at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run(ApacheConnector.java:491)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
.....
```

Comment: Maybe your dockerHost not reachable, you can set dockerHost to `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` and please provide your extended version of `pom.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set **pullNewerImage** to false, as it defaults to true.
For more detail, please refer below link.
https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 10 and docker version : Version 2.0.0.3 (31259) or above, you would need to Enable Expose Daemon without TLS option!

Step 1: Right click on "Docker Desktop is running icon "

Step 2: Click on Settings

Step 3: In “General Tab” you must enable checkbox “Expose Daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS”

This is the error you would see in the subsequent steps if you do not enable this - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

[image]